# SafariViewController in Landscape Mode

Tags: swift, orientation, sfsafariviewcontroller

i have a ViewController that is only in Portrait mode. It presents a SafariViewController. Is it possible to change the orientation of the SafariViewController to Landscape maintaining the Portrait for the ViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with Swift 4.2. You have to add this method in your viewController to maintain portrait orientation

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations:UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}
```

and you also must declare

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Also in your AppDelegate you have to add

```
var myOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return myOrientation
}
```

and this when you are creating the SFSafariViewController

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.myOrientation = .all
```